# What is the difference between Python 2 & Python 3 with stdin.write?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

This code should starts CMD and write a string to a file.
It works for Python 2 but not Python 3?

```
import subprocess

self.process = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True,stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,cwd=None,env=None)
```

Python 2 (This works)

```
self.process.stdin.write("echo It Works >> k:\\test_Python2.txt\n")
```

Python 3 (This not work why???)

```
self.process.stdin.write(("echo It Works >> k:\\test_Python3.txt\n").encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: What is your criteria for deciding "this works" *vs* "this not work"?

Comment: I dont know what Python 2 is from Jan 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I found it...
In Python 3, you should close or flush to finish writing

ex:

import subprocess

self.process = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True,stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,cwd=None,env=None)

self.process.stdin.write(("echo It Works >> k:\test_Python3.txt\n").encode())

## Now you have to flush or close...

self.process.stdin.close()

self.process.stdin.flush()